# jquery load and resize is not working on launch Cordova web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I've created a web application with Cordova, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I try to resize my images it doesn't work, i have to reload the page to fire the callback function. the page:load and resize works well on desktop, the problem occur only with the first page. (on launching)

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var setheight = function () {
    var bottomHeight = $('.bottom-fix').outerHeight();
    var browserHeight = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;
    var swiperContainer = browserHeight - bottomHeight;

    $('.swiper-container').css('height', swiperContainer );
    $('.slide-img-wrapper').each(function () {
        var newSwiperContainer = $('.swiper-container').height() - 40;
        var titleHeight = $(this).prev('.slide-title').outerHeight() + 60;
        var imgHeight = newSwiperContainer - titleHeight;

        $(this).css('height', imgHeight);
        $(this).find('.slide-img').css('height', imgHeight);
    });
};

setheight();
$(window).on("resize", setheight).resize();
$(document).on("page:load", setheight);

});
```

Html :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "login-bookmark" %>

<div class="login-container">
   <div class="popin-login">

   <!-- Slider main container -->

   <div class="swiper-container">

   <!-- Additional required wrapper -->

   <div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <!-- Slides -->

     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class='slide1-img' src="image1.png" />
        <h1 class="slide1-title"> title1 </h1>
     </div>

      <div class="swiper-slide">
         <h1 class="slide-title"> title2 </h1>
         <div class="slide-img-wrapper">
           <img class="slide-img" src="image2.gif" />
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

</div>

<div class="bottom-fix">
  ...
</div>
```

Demo :

[When it's resizing (On page reload)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWhee.png)

[When it's not resizing (On app start)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt6Of.png)

Is there a solution to fire this callback when I start the app ?

Comment: where exactly does the `page:load` event come from?

Comment: on document ready :

` $(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: and why don't you just execute `setheight()` inside the `.ready` function?

Comment: Have you got any Fiddle (&html) or such that illustrates the issue for us?  So we can try if solutions work instead of making "this might work"-guesses.

Comment: I have never seen `page:load` and jQuery 3.0.0 doesn't trigger a `page:load` event after page load (I don't know about cordova, but couldn't find it in the docs). You can define your function before the document is ready and just call it when the document is ready, i.e. `function setheight(){ /* ... */ }` and then `$(function() { setheight(); $(window).on('resize', setheight()); });` btw `$(function() {});` is equal to `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: @SimonHänisch: I've try to execute `setheight()` when the document is ready, it doesn't solve the problem, many thanks anyway!

Comment: @RMo i've updated my post if it helps ! :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to cordova not being fully loaded yet? Try waiting for the `deviceready` callback (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready).